Transition from testing to software development. What can I do to make myself a better candidate for software engineering roles?
My background is in engineering (EE) and testing, and I'm trying to get into software engineering / development. I'm mostly self-taught, and I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction with this transition. I'm trying to figure out how I can make myself a better candidate for software engineering positions. Here's what I've tried, and how I got to my current state.

My previous role (4 years) involved testing hardware products and working with software engineers (embedded) to identify and debug firmware issues. For example, this involved testing hardware prototypes with probes connected to the host machine collecting logs. Through this, I've learned how to analyze logs and root cause issues. I also did a bit of Bash scripting to automate and simplify command flows.

My current role (2+ years) started off with lots of repetitive manual tasks, but I've automated many things over time. I self-started and took initiative to build this automation toolbox, as this was not expected as part of my role, but it has greatly improved the operation scalability for the team. Here's how things developed

Experimentation: It started off with experimenting with Python libraries and seeing how to automate information gathering through some trial-and-error. I started putting together results of multiple libraries, and fully automating a process.
New & Existing Scripts: After experimentation, I figure out how to implement my learnings into new and existing scripts. I also try to follow Python best practices and style guides (e.g. PEP-8) to improve code structure and readability, and sometimes refactor my code.
AI Tools: Anything that I'm unable to find via Google search, I use AI tools (ChatGPT, Bard/Gemini) which often gives accurate solutions. I usually try to understand the generated code before implementing into my scripts.
Data Analysis: I've also developed a script (part of toolbox) to extract relevant spreadsheet data and generate plots for weekly reports. This involves formatting the code accordingly to work with the library (matplotlib)
Documentation: Aside from developing code, I've also put together detailed documentation illustrating my thought process, and clear procedures on how to use the scripts.
Current State: Fast-forward to today, I've developed many Python scripts into an automation toolbox for the team, which automates about 80% of the daily activities, and results in better operational scalability. However, the work is never done, as I have to occasionally account for 1-off scenarios, debug code, and make adjustments depending on changes in product direction.


During the past year, I've also enrolled into an interview prep course and spent time outside work practicing Leetcode problems. I delved into various topics, like graphs, trees, recursion, DP, etc and did corresponding practice problems (in Python).

Some of this practice have also helped my automation scripts, as I learned good practices on how to structure my code and optimize for time complexity.
I've also learned common problem-solving patterns that pertain to the vast majority of problems. I still have more to practice in-order to be interview-ready, especially if they have Leetcode-style interviews
Depending on the level of the role, I might or might not need to learn and practice system design, so I'm not sure how much time and energy I should invest in practicing this at my current stage



State of Industry & Job Market: I'm also aware of industry-wide layoffs in the past year, which continues to be the case. When browsing job postings, I see mostly senior, staff, and principal level positions, especially in my metro area (Bay Area, CA). For positions without the higher-level prefixes (senior, staff, etc), there are often several skills that I haven't learned or have little experience with, but not sure how feasible they are to learn in short periods of time without real-world applications (e.g. on the job).
Concluding Remarks: With the automation work I've done in my current role, I guess I can say that I have 2 years of experience with Python. Overall, am I going in the right direction of this career change into software engineering? What else can I improve on in my current practices, and what else should I be doing to make myself a better candidate for software engineering roles? I know some C++, but not at the same level I know Python. Is knowing mostly Python sufficient for such roles?

"Is knowing mostly Python sufficient for such roles?" - Some jobs will require Python skills. Other jobs may use other languages such as C++, C#, Java, etc... But, in general, you can apply for jobs at lots of companies with Python experience.

Create a public GitHub profile and upload some of your projects. I'm every interview I had people acknowledged it, and it's a great way to advertise your coding skills.

Unfortunately, I'm under NDA and can't share any code, will need to give an overview and describe what I did.

EE written code that I've seen is terse, sometimes hard to read. A lot of places want code that is easy to read / modify as they know that other programmers will need to modify it in the future. I would suggest looking for jobs at engineering type companies, not banks.


there are often several skills that I haven't learned or have little experience with, but not sure how feasible they are to learn in short periods of time without real-world applications (e.g. on the job).

Job advertisements are wish lists. Most points will be "Nice to have" rather than "Must have" requirements.
If you like the look of the job, and meet the most important criteria (e.g. you have experience with the main language used, but have never used the application server or brand of database) then it's worth applying.

Especially if you have similar)related experience that can help you quickly come up to speed on the new tool.

Thanks for the tips! What about the level? Job boards are mostly senior, staff, principal level roles, it's hard to find something that's below senior-level. Even if I encounter one, there's likely tons of competition. What about senior-level roles, even if I have some of the qualifications? Many of these require 5+ YoE, will I be able to get past the automated / AI resume screener?

@RCube123 Give it a try - it's free to find out. There's often very little substitute for "actual time spent doing this professionally" when it comes to experience, but again you might find that people are flexible on that particular requirement.

Consider a smaller company. You can more useful and have more flexibility to learn.
An EE (Assumed to be Electrical Engineer) can't BS their way through a project. They must adhere to standards and test completely. These are concepts that way too many software XXXXXX (Developers, Engineers, Programmers, etc.) just don't get. This puts you ahead of the game and much more likely to be successful in the long run. Just don't lose that mindset.
As a random internet person with 40+ years in software, IMHO, don't look so much at what you've already learned. Expose yourself to different areas to understand what is out there. The simple truth is that logic is logic, only the syntax is different.
Consider things such as Front End vs Back End, Devops (writing scrips), DBA, Data, etc. Then decide what you enjoy doing.
Of course being aware of what is currently in vouge is important, for example don't take up VB6 and COBOL.
The items Xaiver has listed are valuable, use them as part of the process of learning what is out there.

I'm not a python developer, but I answered the question like this a few weeks ago for a person interested in C#.  There are similarities across modern languages though. Here are some things that will make you a formidable candidate

Basic language and syntax
Library/module usage and best practices
Input/output (at a minimum, reading/writing text files)
Database operations.  MySQL/PostgreSQL.  Joins, normalization, grouping, sorting, subqueries, indexes, primary key usage, clustering.
application of any leading ORM (object-relational mapper) libraries, because this cuts down on how much work you have to do for database access.

Then there's the type of development, which is more specialized.  You don't need all of these, but generally any job will align with one of these "buckets":

Web front end development.  This will need HTML, CSS, and Javascript skills.
REST API development.
Reporting.
'Generic' data processing that does not include a front end. It seems you are doing some of this now.

You could prove your worth by showing that you've passed some objective certifications.  Start with free ones.
